# existence of function and derivative

Tags: derivatives

Given a function $f(x)=1/(x-1)$, $f(1)$ is undefined.  $f'(1)$ is also undefined.

Thus my question is, is it always the case for any function if a point is undefined, the derivative of the function at that point will also be undefined?

What about a discontinuity function where a small point is discontinued but exist?

Answer (score 2):

You can not define the derivative at undefined point, say $x_0$ simply because the definition of derivative (difference quotient) needs it:
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
On the other hand, if at the specified point $x_0$, the function is defined, but not continuous, then the difference quotients are well defined, but their limit does not exist, because if you assume the contrary, then the function is differentiable at $x_0$ and thus it must be continuous at $x_0$.